# Android Bitmap : collision Detecting

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android game right now and I would need some help in the collision of the wall on screen. When I drag  the ball in the top and right it able  to collide in wall but when I drag it faster it was able to overlap in the wall

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            // if the player moves
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (playerTouchRect.contains(x, y)) {
                    boolean left = false;
                    boolean right = false;
                    boolean up = false;
                    boolean down = false;
                    boolean canMove = false;
                    boolean foundFinish = false;
                    if (x != pLastXPos) {
                        if (x < pLastXPos) {
                            left = true;
                        } else {
                            right = true;
                        }
                        pLastXPos = x;
                    }
                    if (y != pLastYPos) {
                        if (y < pLastYPos) {
                            up = true;
                        } else {
                            down = true;
                        }
                        pLastYPos = y;
                    }

                    plCellRect = getRectFromPos(x, y);
                    newplRect.set(playerRect);
                    newplRect.left = x - (int) (playerRect.width() / 2);
                    newplRect.right = x + (int) (playerRect.width() / 2);
                    newplRect.top = y - (int) (playerRect.height() / 2);
                    newplRect.bottom = y + (int) (playerRect.height() / 2);
                    int currentRow = 0;
                    int currentCol = 0;
                    currentRow = getRowFromYPos(newplRect.top);
                    currentCol = getColFromXPos(newplRect.right);



                    if(!canMove){
                    canMove = mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[currentRow][currentCol] == Cell.wall;
                    canMove =true;
                    }
                    finishTest = mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[currentRow][currentCol];
                    foundA = finishTest == Cell.valueOf(letterNotGet + "");



                    canMove = mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[currentRow][currentCol] != Cell.wall;
                    canMove = (finishTest == Cell.floor || finishTest == Cell.pl) && canMove;
                    if (canMove) {
                        invalidate();
                        setTitle();
                    }
                    if (foundA) {
                        mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[currentRow][currentCol] = Cell.floor;
                        //  finishTest
                        letterGotten.add(letterNotGet);
                        playCurrentLetter();
                        /*sounds.play(sExplosion, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.5f);*/
                        foundS = letterNotGet == 's';
                        letterNotGet++;
                    }if(foundS){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
                        builder.setTitle(mainActivity.getText(R.string.finished_title));
                        LayoutInflater inflater = mainActivity.getLayoutInflater();
                        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finish, null);
                        builder.setView(view);
                        View closeButton =view.findViewById(R.id.closeGame);
                        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View clicked) {
                                if(clicked.getId() == R.id.closeGame) {
                                    mainActivity.finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog finishDialog = builder.create();
                        finishDialog.show();
                    } 
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "INFO: updated player position");
                        playerRect.set(newplRect);
                        setTouchZone();
                        updatePlayerCell();
                    }
                } // end of (CASE) if playerTouch
                break;
            } // end of (SWITCH) Case motion
            }//end of Switch
            return true;
        }//end of TouchEvent
        private void finish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public int getColFromXPos(int xPos) {
            val = xPos / (pvWidth / mapManager.getCurrentTile().pCols);
            if (val == mapManager.getCurrentTile().pCols) {
                val = mapManager.getCurrentTile().pCols - 1;
            }
            return val;
        }
        /**
         * Given a y pixel position, return the row of the cell it is in This is
         * used when determining the type of adjacent Cells.
         * 
         * @param yPos
         *            y position in pixels
         * @return The cell this position is in
         */
        public int getRowFromYPos(int yPos) {
            val = yPos / (pvHeight / mapManager.getCurrentTile().pRows);
            if (val == mapManager.getCurrentTile().pRows) {
                val = mapManager.getCurrentTile().pRows - 1;
            }
            return val;
        }
        /**
         * When preserving the position we need to know which cell the player is in,
         * so calculate it from the centre on its Rect
         */
        public void updatePlayerCell() {
            plCell.x = (playerRect.left + (playerRect.width() / 2))
                    / (pvWidth / mapManager.getCurrentTile().pCols);
            plCell.y = (playerRect.top + (playerRect.height() / 2))
                    / (pvHeight / mapManager.getCurrentTile().pRows);
            if (mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[plCell.y][plCell.x] == Cell.floor) {
                for (int row = 0; row < mapManager.getCurrentTile().pRows; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < mapManager.getCurrentTile().pCols; col++) {
                        if (mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[row][col] == Cell.pl) {
                            mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[row][col] = Cell.floor;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                mapManager.getCurrentTile().pMaze[plCell.y][plCell.x] = Cell.pl;
            }
        }
        public Rect getRectFromPos(int x, int y) {
            calcCell.left = ((x / cellWidth) + 0) * cellWidth;
            calcCell.right = calcCell.left + cellWidth;
            calcCell.top = ((y / cellHeight) + 0) * cellHeight;
            calcCell.bottom = calcCell.top + cellHeight;
            Log.d(TAG, "Rect: " + calcCell + " Player: " + playerRect);
            return calcCell;
        }
        public void setPlayerRect(Rect newplRect) {
            playerRect.set(newplRect);
        }
        private void setTouchZone() {
            playerTouchRect.set(
                    playerRect.left - playerRect.width() / TOUCH_ZONE,

                    playerRect.top - playerRect.height() / TOUCH_ZONE,
                    playerRect.right + playerRect.width() / TOUCH_ZONE,
                    playerRect.bottom + playerRect.height() / TOUCH_ZONE);
        }
        public Rect getPlayerRect() {
            return playerRect;
        }
        public Point getPlayerCell() {
            return plCell;
        }
        public void setPlayerCell(Point cell) {
            plCell = cell;
        }
    }*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an architectural problem. You can read more about it [here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/).

In essence, your physics simulation (as simple as might be) is coupled to your framerate (which is capped at 60fps). Any events occurring faster than 60Hz cannot be processed accurately hence your bug.

The solution is to run the collision detection on an independent thread and draw the state it calculates at 60fps.

Also, take a look at [these](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=fix+your+timestep) gamedev questions that refer to the same article.